# how to show only starts in django star ratings

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-ratings

I am using django-star ratings and its working fine but along with stars its also showing additional details. I am just writing

```
{% ratings object 18 18 %}
```

in my HTML and its showing me starts but also

> Average: 4.50
>
> Rating Count: 2
>
> You Rated: Not rated
>
> Please log in to rate.

I have read the documentation but I am unable to find anything. I don't want to show this additional details on list page of items but want on detail page of that item.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own `star_ratings/widget.html` showing the detail you want to be shown.

Take a look at `star_ratings/widget_base.html` and you can see all the fields being shown.  Simply include what you want in `star_ratings/widget.html` which extends `star_ratings/widget_base.html` and you should be able to include only the results you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this is working fine but as I already mentioned that - I don't want show additional detail in my list page but yes for detail page of that Item. This new widget.html (without details) is also active in my detail page that I don't want, is there any way to include required widget items in that page only?